# Prove A unbiased estimate of variance in ANOVA

Tags: anova

When i read the book 《Statistical Inference》. I could not solve a proof showed that  $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{k}n_i{(\overline{Y_i} - \overline{\overline{Y}})^2}}{k-1}$ is unbiased estimate of $σ{^2}$. I added the Expectation of $\overline{Y_i}$ and $\overline{\overline{Y}}$ to this equation, but unfortunately the last reduced equation did not show that it is the unbiased estimate of $σ{^2}$. The reason might be the method of solving this question .

Are there any other methods to solve this question? I really look forward for your answer!

Comment: Assuming one-way ANOVA with usual assumptions, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/464358/119261 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3818638/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you so much for answering this question! I will try it again!

Comment: You were already asked not to repost closed questions! Please add necessary information to one of the closed questions, by editing, not repost!

Comment: @StubbornAtom  I get it's answer !! The method is great and I note it down in my textbook.

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen. It's my first time to use stackExchange and not really know the rules of this community, I feel sorry for repost questions.

Comment: OK, been there ... have a look through https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour